# Select a button with a class inside of a table with an id

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<table id="my_table">
<tr>
    <td>
        <button class="btn_save" value="1">Save</button>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to select that button

I have tried:

```
$('#my_table .btn_save').click......
$('table#my_table .btn_save').click......
$('table td .btn_save').click......
$('table td :button.btn_save').click......
```

nothing seems to work, what am I missing?

btw, I cant put an id on the button because this will be a dynamycally generated table with lots of buttons, thats why I chose the class way.

Comment: show your js click handler

Comment: It's probably because it's "dynamic" use delegation :)

Comment: i have a simple alert('hello'); just to check the functionallity of the button,

Comment: show us the code, it will help us get you an accurate answer faster

Comment: see the answers below.. its the ones with `$(document).on('click','element',function`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

all your selectors seem ok. ([Here is a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5GTV/))

I see two possible issues:

Either your data is added dynamically, in which case you need to use event delagation using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on("click",'#my_table .btn_save',function(){
   //what you're doing
});
```

The other possibility is that the selector is added before the data, in which case you need to put your statement in a `$(document).ready` clause

```
$(function(){
    $('#my_table .btn_save').click......
});
```

Comment: ok thanks, it was the delegation stuff, works perfect, thanks again to all!

Answer (score 3):

Since you're generating the table and contents dynamically, delegate the click event by using `.on()`. Try

```
$(document).on('click', '#my_table .btn_save', function(){......
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that table and button exist in dom while you running your code.

```
$(function(){
      var button = jQuery("#my_table button.btn_save")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how often you click these buttons. It is not guaranteed that they submit your form! You will have to change them into `type="submit"` instead of `type="button"`

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about submitting a form, it's about not being able to get the jQuery code to select the button in question.

Comment: Well it is just something I infered. Nothing more.